# MediaPlayer error-getCurrentPosition

Tags: java, android, media-player

Please teach me how can I solve a MediaPlayer error. I have Mediaplayer, MediaController and listview. When I touch the list, a song starts with MediaController, but when I touch `keycode_home` and restart my app, the error occurs. Here is my code and error.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {}: 
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at android.media.MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(Native Method)


    int si[]={R.raw.sample1,R.raw.sample2,R.raw.sample3};
    onCreate

    ItemBean IB1 = new ItemBean();
    IB1.setName("sample1");
    IB1.setUrl("http~");

    ItemBean IB2 = new ItemBean();
     IB2.setName("sample2");
    IB2.setUrl("http~");

    ItemBean IB3 = new ItemBean();
    IB3.setName("sample3");
    IB3.setUrl("http~");

    List<ItemBean> list = new ArrayList<ItemBean>();
    list.add(IB1);
    list.add(IB2);
    list.add(IB3);

    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    controller = new MediaController(this);
    controller.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.mediaController));
    controller.setMediaPlayer(this);

    list2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.song_list);
    SonglistAdapter_test adapter = new SonglistAdapter_test(getApplicationContext(),list);
    list2.setAdapter(adapter);
    list2.setOnItemClickListener(this);
     }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.release();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(SongsActivity.this,si[position]);
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    controller.setEnabled(true);
                    controller.show(mp.getDuration());
                    mp.start();
                    try {
                        Method m = android.widget.MediaController.class.getDeclaredMethod("updatePausePlay");
                        m.setAccessible(true);
                        m.invoke(controller);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            });
         }
        });
       }
    @Override
    public void start(){
    mp.start();    }

    @Override
    public void pause(){
    mp.pause();   }

    @Override
    public int getDuration(){
    return mp.getDuration();  }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentPosition(){
    return mp.getCurrentPosition(); }

    @Override
    public void seekTo(int pos){
    mp.seekTo(pos);  }

    @Override
    public boolean isPlaying(){
    return mp.isPlaying(); }

    @Override
    public int getBufferPercentage(){
    return 0; }

    @Override
    public boolean canPause(){
    return true;    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekBackward(){
    return true;    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekForward(){
    return true;    }

    @Override
    public int getAudioSessionId(){
    return 0;    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    controller.hide();
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();
    controller.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
      finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: @Stedy I am glad to be edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `onStop()` method -- you are releasing your media player there and not recreating it before you show the controller during `onRestart()`. The `onStop()` method is not the same as `onDestroy()` -- `onStop()` doesn't mean that your activity will necessarily run through `onCreate()` again when it is resumed.

You should have a look at the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) to get a better understanding of when these events occur.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!  I reviewed Activity Lifecycle and MediaPlayer State diagram. I could noticed what I made mistakes!